# Rust itertools combinations with variable length counts

Tags: math, rust, combinations, permutation, rust-itertools

I want to calculate a vector's combination.

I am able to do it easily using `itertools::Itertools:combinations` trait like this:

```rust
vec![1, 2, 3].iter().combinations(2).for_each(|x| {
    println!("{:?}", x);
});
```

But I want to specify the combination lengths as well as counts of these lengths. As an example:

```py
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# 1 group with a length of 3 and 1 group with a length of 2
len_counts = { 3: 1, 2: 1 }

combinations = [
    [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}]
    [{0, 1, 3}, {2, 4}]
    [{0, 1, 4}, {2, 3}]
    [{0, 2, 3}, {1, 4}]
    [{0, 2, 4}, {1, 3}]
    [{0, 3, 4}, {1, 2}]
    [{1, 2, 3}, {0, 4}]
    [{1, 2, 4}, {0, 3}]
    [{1, 3, 4}, {0, 2}]
    [{2, 3, 4}, {0, 1}]
]
```

I want it to be lazy-loaded and as clean as possible. I tried to get this output for some time but couldn't succeed. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The order of combinations and data structures used for representing the variables are not important.

Comment: I don't think `len_counts = { 3: 1, 2: 1 }` will work, because maps in rust are not ordered.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, it doesn't need to be ordered and it doesn't have to be map. It can be any datatype as long as it contains the necessary data.

Comment: Does it have to support an empty `values` or `len_counts`?

Comment: Yes but I don't think it would be hard to have a check for that. Also sum of all products of counts and lengths in `len_counts` has to be equal to length of `values`. So in this example `1 * 3 + 1 * 2 = len(values) = 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of thought, I sadly wasn't able to come up with a clean and easy solution.

Nonetheless, I came up with a solution :) although it's quite messy, I'm afraid :D

```
use std::{collections::HashSet, iter::Peekable};

use itertools::{Combinations, Itertools};

// This struct is so we can `HashSet` by reference address.
// This prevents that `T` needs to be hashable.
struct GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T> GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T> {
    fn new(val: &'a T) -> Self {
        Self(val)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> std::hash::Hash for GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T> {
    fn hash<H: std::hash::Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        std::ptr::hash(self.0, state);
    }
}

impl<'a, T> PartialEq for GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        std::ptr::eq(self.0, other.0)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Clone for GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self(self.0)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Eq for GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T> {}

struct GroupedCombinations<'a, T> {
    values: HashSet<GroupedCombinationsValue<'a, T>>,
    leftover_counts: &'a [usize],
    iter: Peekable<Combinations<std::vec::IntoIter<&'a T>>>,
    child_iter: Option<Box<GroupedCombinations<'a, T>>>,
}

impl<'a, T> GroupedCombinations<'a, T> {
    fn new(values: Vec<&'a T>, counts: &'a [usize]) -> Self {
        let count;
        let leftover_counts;

        if counts.len() == 0 {
            count = 0;
            leftover_counts = counts;
        } else {
            count = counts[0];
            leftover_counts = &counts[1..];
        }

        let iter = values.clone().into_iter().combinations(count).peekable();
        let values = values
            .into_iter()
            .map(GroupedCombinationsValue::new)
            .collect::<HashSet<_>>();

        Self {
            values,
            leftover_counts,
            iter,
            child_iter: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for GroupedCombinations<'a, T> {
    type Item = Vec<Vec<&'a T>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let local_value = self.iter.peek()?;

        if self.child_iter.is_none() && !self.leftover_counts.is_empty() {
            let child_values = self
                .values
                .difference(
                    &local_value
                        .iter()
                        .cloned()
                        .map(GroupedCombinationsValue::new)
                        .collect(),
                )
                .map(|e| e.0)
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            self.child_iter = Some(Box::new(Self::new(child_values, self.leftover_counts)));
        }

        let mut result = vec![];
        if !local_value.is_empty() {
            result.extend_from_slice(&[local_value.clone()]);
        }

        if let Some(child_iter) = &mut self.child_iter {
            match child_iter.next() {
                Some(child_value) => {
                    result.extend(child_value);
                    Some(result)
                }
                None => {
                    self.child_iter = None;
                    self.iter.next();
                    self.next()
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.iter.next();
            Some(result)
        }
    }
}

fn grouped_combinations<'a, T>(values: &'a [T], counts: &'a [usize]) -> GroupedCombinations<'a, T> {
    GroupedCombinations::new(values.iter().collect(), counts)
}

fn main() {
    let values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    let counts = [3, 2];

    let combinations = grouped_combinations(&values, &counts);

    for combination in combinations {
        println!("{:?}", combination);
    }
}
```

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[0, 1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]]
[[0, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
[[0, 2, 4], [1, 3]]
[[0, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 0]]
[[1, 2, 4], [3, 0]]
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 0]]
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is partition a series of `n` items into `m` sets where each set has a predefined length?
You can do this with a recursive approach:

Given a series of lengths `lengths` and the desired list of things `items`:

- first check if `lengths` is empty, if so yield an empty list and stop
- pop the first length from `lengths` and store it in `current_length`
- for each combination `combination` of `items` with length `current_length` do:

  1. generate a new list `remaining_items` with all items from `items` which are not included in `combination`
  2. do a recursive call of this function with arguments `lengths` and `remaining_items` and for each result `rest` do:

     - yield `rest` with `combination` prepended

This will give you a generator which will produce the desired result without any duplicates.

If you are ok with using rust nightly and the `itertools` library an implementation is:

```rust
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::{ops::Generator, iter::FromIterator, pin::Pin};
use std::ops::GeneratorState;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn partition_series(sizes: Vec<usize>, items: Vec<u64>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Vec<Vec<u64>>> {
    GeneratorToIterator(move || {
        if sizes.len() == 0 {
            yield vec![];
            return;
        }
        
        let current_size = sizes[0];
        for combination in items.clone().into_iter().combinations(current_size) {
            let remaining_items: Vec<u64> = items
                .clone()
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|n| !combination.contains(n))
                .collect();

            let inner_generator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Vec<Vec<u64>>>> = Box::new(partition_series(sizes[1..].into(), remaining_items));
            for mut rest in inner_generator {
                rest.insert(0, combination.clone());
                yield rest;
            } 
        }
    })
}

struct GeneratorToIterator<G>(G);

impl<G> Iterator for GeneratorToIterator<G>
where
    G: Generator<Return = ()>,
{
    type Item = G::Yield;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let me = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut self.0) };
        match me.resume(()) {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(x) => Some(x),
            GeneratorState::Complete(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can call for a series of number from 0 to n via:

```rust
fn main() {
    let sizes = vec![3, 2];
    let total_size = sizes.iter().sum::<usize>() as u64;
    let numbers = Vec::from_iter(0..total_size);
    for combination in partition_series(sizes, numbers) {
        println!("{:?}", combination);
    }
}
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[0, 1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]]
[[0, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
[[0, 2, 4], [1, 3]]
[[0, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 4]]
[[1, 2, 4], [0, 3]]
[[1, 3, 4], [0, 2]]
[[2, 3, 4], [0, 1]]
```

Since the rust implementation might be a bit difficult to understand due to the somewhat unwieldy generator ergonomics, here is a python implementation as wel:

```py
from typing import Iterable, List
from itertools import combinations


def main():
    for combination in generate_next([2, 2, 1]):
        print(combination)

def generate_next(sizes: List[int]) -> Iterable[List[List[int]]]:
    total_size = sum(sizes)
    numbers = list(range(total_size))
    yield from generate_next_internal(sizes, numbers)

def generate_next_internal(sizes: List[int], remaining: List[int]) -> Iterable[List[List[int]]]:
    if len(sizes) == 0:
        yield []
        return

    current_size = sizes.pop(0)

    for combination in combinations(list(remaining), current_size):
        new_remaining = [i for i in remaining if i not in combination]
        for rest in generate_next_internal(list(sizes), new_remaining):
            rest.insert(0, list(combination))
            yield rest



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```